# Send order email gives internal server error and place order redirects to cart preview

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I am new to magento. When I place an order the page redirects to shopping cart and when I try to send order confirmation email it says internal server error.

Comment: `when I try to send order confirmation email` wherre you are getting internal server error ? also is `place order` redirects to cart page for all payemnt methods ?

Comment: Please check your server error logs, what kind of error you are getting. Internal server can be anything